# Problem with Selenium configuration in Eclipse

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, eclipse

[image]

I am trying to configure Selenium WebDriver with Eclipse IDE. While running my code I am getting `java exception has occurred` error. How to fix this?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Test {


    static WebDriver driver1=new ChromeDriver();
    String user="rutvisoni"; 
    String pass="12Abcd";

    public void setup() throws IOException
    {
        driver1.manage().window().maximize();
        driver1.get("http://example.com");

        //File inputFile = new ClassPathResource("E:\\Selenium Jar\\chromedriver.exe").getFile();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Selenium Jar\\chromedriver.exe");

    }


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Test t1=new Test();
        t1.setup();

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you configured the environment variable path for JAVA in your computer?

Comment: yes Configured the environment variable path for JAVA

Comment: Would you share your code so that people here can understand the problem and try to figure out a solution?

Comment: Please check browser version.Is it compitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing chrome in a wrong way. In your code you have maximized browser and called the URL, before even setting up the chrome profile. You can give a try to below code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium Jar\\chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver1.manage().window().maximize();
            driver1.get("http://example.com");
```

And please remove the code line mentioned below from your code:

```
static WebDriver driver1=new ChromeDriver();
```

If you still face same exception, please share the exception details.